# Validate user account via mailbox symfony3

Tags: php, symfony

I would like to do a registration email validation when a member clicks on a link in his mailbox with symfony3 ... without using FOSuserBundle

I add 2 fields in my user entity, a boolean $ validMail attribute, and a string code_validation to generate a random number on each enrollment.

By default, I initialize $validMail to false, I generate a random code in my entity user with each registration and i would like to detect when the user validates the email.

Here is my service :

```
namespace AppBundle\Services;

use AppBundle\Entity\User;
use AppBundle\Form\InscriptionType;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormFactory;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Tests\Encoder\PasswordEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;


class Securite implements  ContainerAwareInterface
{

    private $doctrine;
    private $form;
    private $session;
    private $authenticationUtils;


    /**
     * @var ContainerInterface
     */
    private $container;

    /**
     * @var PasswordEncoder
     */
    private $passwordEncoder;


    /**
     * @var \Swift_Mailer
     */
    private $mailer;
    private $twig;

    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function __construct(EntityManager $doctrine, Session $session, FormFactory $form, AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils, UserPasswordEncoder $passwordEncoder, \Swift_Mailer $mailer, \Twig_Environment $twig)
    {
        $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
        $this->session = $session;
        $this->form = $form;
        $this->authenticationUtils = $authenticationUtils;
        $this->passwordEncoder = $passwordEncoder;
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
        $this->twig = $twig;
    }


    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $inscription = new User();

        $form = $this->form->create(InscriptionType::class, $inscription);

        if ($request->isMethod('POST') && $form->handleRequest($request)->isValid())
        {

            $data = $form->getData();
            $this->session->set('inscription', $data);

            $inscription->setValidMail(false);

            $password = $inscription->getPassword();

            $this->cryptPassword($inscription, $password);

            $this->doctrine->persist($inscription);
            $this->doctrine->flush();
            $this->session->getFlashBag()->add("success", "inscription confirmée, veuillez confirmer votre email");

            $this->isValidMail();

        }
        return $form;
    }


    public function cryptPassword(User $user, $plainPassword)
    {
        $encoder = $this->passwordEncoder;

        $encoded = $encoder->encodePassword($user, $plainPassword);

        $user->setPassword($encoded);
    }


    public function isValidMail()
    {
        $inscription = $this->session->get('inscription');

        if ($inscription) {
            $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
                ->setCharset('UTF-8')
                ->setSubject('Veuillez confirmer votre inscription')
                ->setBody($this->twig->render('back/email_inscription.html.twig', array(
                    'username'        => $inscription->getUsername(),
                    'password'         => $inscription->getPassword(),
                    'code_validation' => $inscription->getCodeValidation(),
                )))
                ->setContentType('text/html')
                ->setFrom('test@gmail.com')
                ->setTo($inscription->getUsername());

            $this->mailer->send($message);
        }
    }
}
```

I do not know how to detect when the user clicks on the link in his mailbox, refresh the page...I try to follow tutorials but it seems too complicated. What is the simplest way?

Answer (score 0):

Why not to pass token in request ($_GET parameter). For example url:

```
www.blah.com/confirm_register?token=asdawddazvaefas
```

then take that token:

```
$token = $request->attributes->get('token');
```

and then check if that token exists in database if exists update that user field $validEmail to true.

Answer (score 0):

Validation link has to include code_validation as URL parameter. Then you create new route for email validation.

When user clicks the link in the mailbox he visits the email validation route with the parameter. Then you validate GET parameter as Elimsas says.